# (Optaplanner issue) Not able to replicate a java working method in benchmarking xml

Tags: benchmarking, optaplanner

**I have created a solver that uses a probabilistic change move selector (code below). When I execute it, everything works fine.**

```
public SolverFactory<OptaplannerSolution> customSolverFactory_10(OptaplannerAlgorithm params) {

VehicleDriverTimetableOptaplannerAlgorithm par = (VehicleDriverTimetableOptaplannerAlgorithm) params;
    
LOGGER.info("=============================================");
    LOGGER.info("=====================Solution===================");

    
    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig cms = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();      
    cms.setSelectionOrder(SelectionOrder.PROBABILISTIC);
    cms.setCacheType(SelectionCacheType.STEP);      
    cms.setSelectedCountLimit(100l);        
    cms.setProbabilityWeightFactoryClass(SelectionProbabilityWeightFactoryM.class); 
    
    ConstructionHeuristicForagerConfig forager = new ConstructionHeuristicForagerConfig();
    forager.setPickEarlyType(ConstructionHeuristicPickEarlyType.FIRST_FEASIBLE_SCORE_OR_NON_DETERIORATING_HARD);        
    ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig ch = new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig()
            .withConstructionHeuristicType(ConstructionHeuristicType.FIRST_FIT_DECREASING)
            .withForagerConfig(forager);
    ch.setMoveSelectorConfigList(Collections.singletonList(cms));
    
    LocalSearchForagerConfig localSearchForager = new LocalSearchForagerConfig();
    localSearchForager.setAcceptedCountLimit(100);
    localSearchForager.setPickEarlyType(LocalSearchPickEarlyType.FIRST_LAST_STEP_SCORE_IMPROVING);
    
    LocalSearchAcceptorConfig localSearchAcceptor = new LocalSearchAcceptorConfig();
    localSearchAcceptor.setEntityTabuSize(10);
    //LocalSearchPhaseConfig ls=  new LocalSearchPhaseConfig().withLocalSearchType(LocalSearchType.TABU_SEARCH)
    /**
     * 
     * A MoveSelector which selects the possible moves of the current solution. See the chapter move and neighborhood selection.
        An Acceptor which filters out unacceptable moves.

        A Forager which gathers accepted moves and picks the next step from them.
     */
    
    LocalSearchPhaseConfig ls= new LocalSearchPhaseConfig().withForagerConfig(localSearchForager ).withAcceptorConfig(localSearchAcceptor);
    ls.setMoveSelectorConfig(cms);


    ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig sd = new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig()
            .withEasyScoreCalculatorClass(VehicleDriverTimetableOptaplannerScoreCalculator.class);

    
    return SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig().withSolutionClass(VehicleDriverTimetableOptaplannerSolution.class)
                    .withEntityClasses(OPService.class)
                    .withPhases(ch,ls)
                    .withScoreDirectorFactory(sd)
                    .withTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig()
                            .withUnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit((long) par.maxUnimproved)
                            .withBestScoreLimit("0hard/0medium/0soft").withSecondsSpentLimit((long) par.maxTime)));
```

**I'm trying to benchmark the solver against other solvers using the optaplanner benchmarking tool. To do so, I translated the solver definition into XML (see code).**

```
<solverBenchmark>
    <name>BASE</name>
    <solver>
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
                <selectionOrder>PROBABILISTIC</selectionOrder>
<probabilityWeightFactoryClass>org.eurecat.engine.dtos.problems.vehicle_driver_timetable.SelectionProbabilityWeightFactoryM</probabilityWeightFactoryClass>
                <selectedCountLimit>100</selectedCountLimit>
            </changeMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <forager>
            <pickEarlyType>FIRST_FEASIBLE_SCORE_OR_NON_DETERIORATING_HARD</pickEarlyType>
        </forager>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch>
        <acceptor>
            <entityTabuSize>10</entityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <pickEarlyType>FIRST_LAST_STEP_SCORE_IMPROVING</pickEarlyType>
            <acceptedCountLimit>100</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>
    </solver>
</solverBenchmark>
```

**When I run the benchmark the following exception is thrown:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.optaplanner.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmarkException: Benchmarking failed: failureCount (1). The exception of the firstFailureSingleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_BASE_0) is chained.at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkingEnded(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:311)at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmark(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:84)at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:409)at org.eurecat.engine.Benchmarking.main(Benchmarking.java:225)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.NavigableMap.size()" because "this.cachedMoveMap" is nullat org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.ProbabilityMoveSelector.getSize(ProbabilityMoveSelector.java:87)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.SelectedCountLimitMoveSelector.getSize(SelectedCountLimitMoveSelector.java:42)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.IterableSelector.spliterator(IterableSelector.java:24)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector.toStream(UnionMoveSelector.java:114)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelector.iterator(UnionMoveSelector.java:94)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacer$QueuedEntityPlacingIterator.createUpcomingSelection(QueuedEntityPlacer.java:56)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacer$QueuedEntityPlacingIterator.createUpcomingSelection(QueuedEntityPlacer.java:31)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.iterator.UpcomingSelectionIterator.hasNext(UpcomingSelectionIterator.java:27)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:45)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:83)at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:193)at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:108)at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:28)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I'm working with optaplanner 9.44.0.Final version

I'm trying to benchmark the existing and functional method but I'm getting the error mentioned, I'm using optaplanner 9.44.0.Final version, also working with graddle.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    Cannot invoke "java.util.NavigableMap.size()" because "this.cachedMoveMap" is null
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.decorator.ProbabilityMoveSelector.getSize(ProbabilityMoveSelector.java:87)
```

This looks suspiciously similar to a [known issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/169) which [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/) (and OptaPlanner) have not fixed yet. Step cache is the problem there.

It is curious that you see the problem in the benchmarker and not in the solver. That behavior would be very hard to explain, unless the two configs are not in fact equivalent, but I do not have enough information to say that with confidence. A runnable piece of code to reproduce the behavior would either confirm or deny my suspicion.